# NullPointer Exception on map.get()

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, nullpointerexception, hashmap

```
public class SumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> l3=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> l4=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
                int j=0;

      String[] wordCount = new String[100];
      List<String> Final = new ArrayList<String>();
      String mapop = "";
        for (Text value : values) {

            wordCount[j] =value.toString();
            j++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
            //Final= Final+","+wordCount[i];
            Final.add(wordCount[i]);

        }

        String key1=key.toString();
        map.put(key1, Final);


        l1.add("1");
        l2=(map.get("1"));
        int total_nodes=l2.size();

        for(int i=0;i<total_nodes;i++)
        {   

            if(l2.size()!=1)
          { 
            l1.add(l2.get(0));

            **l3=map.get(l2.get(0));**

            **int cs=l3.size()**;//---------------NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE

            for(int e=1;e<l2.size();e++)
            {

                for(int k=0;k<cs;k++)
                {
                    String keymap=l2.get(e);
                    if(keymap==l3.get(k)){

                       l4.add(keymap);
                       //System.out.println(l4);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }



}
```

This code runs perfectly in java but throws  NULL pointer exception in mapreduce. Value of l3(list) is not getting initialized at all. I am trying to implement bruteforce algorithm for finding cliques. The program has static inputs with 5 nodes in a graph all connected to each other. 
This is not the whole program but just a snippet of the code where the error is shown.

Comment: l2.get(0) is not key for map... You never set it. And please, refactor this thing...